# How Do I solve Interface Binding Error In Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an Issue trying to Bind my PostForm with an Image Uploading Ability for a Post Made, However there is a functional Profile picture coding which accepts images and save the name to the data base and to avoid error, it adds uuid1 to the image name which is saved on the data base and the image itself is saved in the static folder, image section where it is called upon when needed, all part of the UserForm, but for the PostForm, the method is the same, but instead of a profile picture, it is a post image which should appear there and it keeps giving me interface error, however if the image is excluded, the Post is added to the Database successfully, please I need your help to know what is going wrong, Here is the Code:

```
@app.route('/add-post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        if request.files['post_image']:
            post_image = request.files['post_image']
            post_filename = secure_filename(post_image.filename)
            post_name = str(uuid.uuid1()) + "_" + post_filename         
            saver = request.files['post_image']
            post_image = str(uuid.uuid1()) + "_" + post_filename

            try:
                db.session.commit()
                saver.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], post_name))

            except:
                flash("Error! Looks Like There Was a Problem... Try Again!")

        else:
            db.session.commit()
                

        poster = current_user.id
        post = Posts(title=form.title.data, post_image=form.post_image.data, content=form.content.data, poster_id=poster, slug=form.slug.data)
        
        form.title.data = ''
        form.content.data = ''
        form.slug.data = ''
        form.post_image.data = ''

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Blog Post Submitted Successfully !")

    return render_template("add_post.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of trying and having errors, I finally got the hang of it... I will post the answer below:

```py
@app.route('/add-post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm()
            
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        poster = current_user.id
        post = Posts(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, file=form.file.data, poster_id=poster, slug=form.slug.data)

        if request.files['file']:
            upload.file = request.files['file']

            filename = secure_filename(upload.file.filename)

            file_name = str(uuid.uuid1()) + "_" + filename
            
            saver = request.files['file']

            post.file = file_name

            try:
                db.session.add(post)
                db.session.commit()
                saver.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name))
                flash("User Updated Successfully !")
                return render_template("add_post.html",
                    form=form)
            except:
                flash("Error! Looks Like There Was a Problem... Try Again!")
                return render_template("add_post.html",
                    form=form)
        else:
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("User Updated Successfully !")
            return render_template("add_post.html",
                form=form)
        
        form.title.data = ''
        form.content.data = ''
        form.slug.data = ''

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template("add_post.html",
            form=form,
            id = id or 1)
```